# How can I dynamically name an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am using jQuery and JSON to pull data from a database. Each row of the database is a different product and each product has a number of properties associated with it.

What I'm trying to do in js, is create a named array for each product containing all of the products properties. I know how to pull the data from JSON. I know how to construct the Array.

What I don't know is how to create an array name dynamically. Can someone help me out?

I am trying to name the array based on a field in the database. In the structure of my existing and working script, it's referenced as data.cssid. I'd like to use the value of data.cssid as the name of the array and then populate the array.

```
$.getJSON("products.php",function(data){
    $.each(data.products, function(i,data){
        var data.cssid = new Array();
        data.cssid[0] = data.productid;
        ...
        etc
    });
});
```

I know the code above is completely wrong, but it illustrates the idea. Where I declare "var data.cssid", I want to use the actual value of data.cssid as the name of the new array.

EDIT:

I've tried the methods mentioned here (except for eval). The code is below and is not really that different than my original post, except that I'm using a Object constructor.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("productscript.php",function(data){
    $.each(data.products, function(i,data){
        var arrayName = data.cssid;
        obj[arrayName] = new Array();
        obj[arrayName][0] = data.productid;
        obj[arrayName][1] = data.productname;
        obj[arrayName][2] = data.cssid;
        obj[arrayName][3] = data.benefits;
        alert(obj[arrayName]); //WORKS
        alert(obj.shoe); //WORKS WHEN arrayName = shoe, otherwise undefined
    });
});
});
```

The alert for the non-specific obj[arrayName] works and shows the arrays in all their magnificence. 
But, when I try to access a specific array by name alert(obj.shoe), it works only when the arrayName = shoe. Next iteration it fails and it can't be accessed outside of this function.

I hope this helps clarify the problem and how to solve it. I really appreciate all of the input and am trying everything you guys suggest.

PROGRESS (THE SOLUTION):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("productscript.php",function(data){
    $.each(data.products, function(i,data){
        var arrayName = data.cssid;
        window[arrayName] = new Array();
        var arr = window[data.cssid];
        arr[0] = data.productid;
        arr[1] = data.productname;
        arr[2] = data.cssid;
        arr[3] = data.benefits;
        alert(window[arrayName]); //WORKS
        alert(arrayName); //WORKS
        alert(shoe); //WORKS

    });
});
});
function showAlert() {
    alert(shoe); //WORKS when activated by button click
}
```

Thanks to everybody for your input.

Comment: Why? What do you want to do with the variable?

Comment: You could use `eval`, but I won't put that as an answer because it's probably not a good idea.  E.g. `eval('var ' + data.cssid + ' = new Array()');`

Comment: I'm trying to use the properties of each product in other scripts. I had originally built this so that the necessary html was output from the JSON. Now I think I need to make it more flexible and was thinking constructing arrays first and then accessing the arrays to construct the html and formulas would be the correct method.

So, when I construct the HTML for the product "shoe", I access the array and plug the variables into my script.

Comment: Steven, I saw that method too and also read that eval is evil, so I'm trying to avoid that. Though, I admit I don't know why eval is evil.

Comment: Referring to your second block of code here - have you tried putting "var obj = {};" in the scope where you want it to live, such as at the top? Without that, you may just be creating a new obj variable in each loop iteration, then discarding it.

Comment: Nick... that might be it. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

do you still want the array to be on the `data` object?

```
data[data.cssid] = new Array();
```

otherwise, you can assign it to any other object. assigning it to the `window` object, will make it globally available

```
window[data.cssid] = new Array();
```

... then if the value of `data.cssid` is `"abc"` then you can access it like so

```
abc[0] = data.productid;
```

Comment: I do want to be able to access the arrays globally.

1. How do I populate the array using the window[] method? Would it be:
 window[data.cssid][0] = data.products;

2. How do I access the array after it's been constructed this way? If the value of data.cssid was "shoe", would I be able to access the array using shoe[i] or some other syntax?

Comment: You'd have to use `window["shoe"]` still.  Unless you knew that it was shoe and hardcoded `shoe`.  x[ str ] is the way of accessing a property on x with a string (as opposed to x.prop).

Comment: David, if I don't know the value of data.cssid, how would I populate?

Comment: @Duffy Dolan: yes, you can write `window[data.cssid][0] = data.products;`, or you can write `window[data.cssid] = new Array(); var arr = window[data.cssid]; arr[0] = data.products`. 2. you can access it `window[data.cssid][0]` as well, or, if you know that `data.cssid` is `"shoe"` you can write `shoe[0]`.

Comment: David, check the PROGRESS edit in my post. Using this method has me closer than ever, but I'm failing when I try to access the array from outside the original function.

Comment: @Duffy Dolan: the problem you're facing now is quite different. in a linear execution path, your alert would indeed work. what's happening here is that the function you're passing to `getJSON` is not being executed until *after* the HTTP request to `productscript.php`. While that request is being made, the javascript engine moves on to execute other code, so your alert is actually being executed *before* the definition of `shoe`. to support an asynchronous execution path, which AJAX will give you, you need to work with callbacks - i.e. call a function from within your `each` and *that*

Comment: ... function will be able to access `shoe`

Comment: got it! makes perfect sense. Better yet, it works! Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

No not possible. PHP has "variable variables"; Javascript does not.

You could however assign the array to an extant object :

```
var obj = {};
var name = 'foo';
obj[name] = 1;

alert(obj.foo) // alerts "1"
```

Honestly not sure why you'd need that capability anyway. Can you post more code? There's probably a decent workaround if the above doesn't help.

Comment: I'm trying this and the other methods out now. I will post shortly and include more code if I don't get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a property on an object by name like this:

```
var obj = {};  //Or, new Object()
obj[data.cssid] = new Array();
```

However, if you're just making a local variable, there is no point; you can simply name the array `newData` (or something like that), as you will only ever be dealing with a single array at a time.